# How to change system default date time on Debian permanently?

Tags: linux, unix, unix-timestamp

How to change system default date time on Debian permanently?

I tried following command

```
# date --set="12 MAY 2012 12:12:12 PM"

# hwclock --systoh
```

But date-time is getting changed temporary.

After few seconds, current date is popping again.

Did I miss something?

Update

System is guest OS on virtual box, where ntp is not enabled.

While ntp is enabled in host OS.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `NTP` is setting your time over internet.... You need to stop `NTP`.
Try these commands:

```
sudo service ntp stop
```

To prevent it from starting at boot:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f ntp remove
```

You may need to uninstall `ntpd` if needed. Even though you uninstall `ntpd`, `ntpdate` will be still installed in your system. You can add exit status to disable it.
Add `exit 0` to `/etc/default/ntpdate`.

Answer (score 2):

Just execute this command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

You will be asked for the timezone.

[debian docs](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/system-administrator/ch-sysadmin-time.html#s-tzconfig) recommends using `tzconfig`, but it seems to be deprecated in favor of `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Comment: I see nothing about timezones in the question.

Comment: @jwodder - ...but user wants to change the machine local time. This is the better way if your desired local time match a timezone one. I disagree with the down vote.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a systemd system then you have to use timedatectl:

```
timedatectl set-ntp false 
timedatectl set-time '2018-12-12 12:12:12'
```